# Sublime Text 2: Replace for an entire folder

Tags: sublimetext2

How can I search for all occurrences of `class="span` and replace with `class="col-md-` within an entire project folder?

I'm using Sublime Text 2, and would really appreciate a function where it shows each occurrence and asks if the change is ok. Does such a function exist?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107208/sublime-text-2-find-and-replace-globally-all-files-and-in-all-directories

Comment: When you do search described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107208/sublime-text-2-find-and-replace-globally-all-files-and-in-all-directories new file will open and show you results, so you can browser through it and see if you can replace all occurences or need to go file-by-file