# How can I easily add an "IF EXISTS" condition to >1500 T-SQL scripts?

Tags: regex, t-sql, sublimetext2

I have 1500 odd T-SQL scripts which are formatted as follows:

```
DROP PROCEDURE <stored proc name>

CREATE PROCEDURE 
<stored proc definition>
```

I've been tasked to insert an IF EXISTS condition on all of them, before they try to drop the procedure, so the scripts won't fail the first time they run.

I'm looking for an efficient way (in a windows 7 environment) to modify all these scripts to add the following condition before the drop statement. I'm not too keen on modifying them manually!

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'<stored proc name>') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
```

EDIT:
Sublime text editor with Regex seems to  be a good tool to use. I've never used Regex before but I've figured out that

```
(?<=DROP PROCEDURE ).*
```

Will find everything on the line after "stored procedure". I want to put this in the Replace statement but it doesn't seem to be reading it (the actual regex is just inserted into the code). How can I do this?

Comment: You could use a text editor, such as sublime, and use regex to do a search and replace. Is this something you've tried already?

Comment: How are they stored presently? Excel is handy for creating queries.

Comment: @ShafiqJetha I haven't used that application before. I'll give it a try and see if I can batch edit.

Comment: @GoatCO They're just a bunch of sql text files stored on a local drive.

Comment: Either a text editor as was suggested, or you could write a little console app to do it (or a python script, if you know python)

Answer (score 0):

@Shafiq Jetha renders good advice. Give Sublime Text a whirl:

1. Download Sublime Text from here: http://www.sublimetext.com/3
2. In Windows Explorer, select all your .sql file > opposite click > Open With > Sublime Text
3. Use a Regular Expressions and [Search and Replace - Multiple Files](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html)

[This post can help with the Search and Replace - Multiple Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107208/sublime-text-2-find-and-replace-globally-all-files-and-in-all-directories)

[This can help with the Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: I think the hardest part about this would be getting Windows to open 1500 files at once.